# Carriage Return in Param File

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

Is there a way I can insert a carriage return in a parameter file?

I have a variable with the following:

$$test = Hello, I am testing

This is supposed to be a variable for an email message and I want a carriage return after the Hello,

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use it in parameter file itself. But you can use a character that will later on be replaced with `CHR(10)` in an `Expression Transformation`.